# SOQL query to get both direct and indirect contacts on an account?

Tags: trigger, soql, accountcontactrelation

Looking at expanding this trigger to auto add all related contacts, not just those directly related. Having a tough time figuring this one out.

```
trigger InsertAccountContactsToOpportunityContactRole on Opportunity (after update) {
    
    //list of opportunities
    List<Opportunity> opportunities_in = trigger.new;
    
    //Loops through all the opps in this list
    for(Opportunity opp: opportunities_in){
        
        //validate that they are not existing employer business or emergying account deployment
        if(Opp.RecordTypeId != '0121I000001CDxfQAG' || Opp.RecordTypeId != '0121I000000JlQMQA0' ){
            
            //get the id of all involved accounts
            Set<ID> accountIds = new Set<ID>();
            for(Opportunity opt:opportunities_in){
                accountIds.add(opt.AccountId);
                }
    
            //get all contacts for those accounts
            list<Contact> contacts = new list<Contact>();
            //testing
            for (Id accountId: accountIds){
            contacts = [select id, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];
            }
            
            //validates that there are contacts to continue code
            if(contacts.size()>0){
            
                //organize these contacts by account
                Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsByAccount = new Map<ID,List<Contact>>();
                for(Contact c:contacts){
                    if(contactsByAccount.get(c.AccountId) == null){
                    contactsByAccount.put(c.AccountId,new List<Contact>());
                    }
                    contactsByAccount.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
                }
        
                // check to see if the Opportunity already has a contact role.  If it does, add to a set of Ids to exclude
                List<OpportunityContactRole> existingOCR = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
                Set<Id> existingOCRIds = new Set<Id>();
                existingOCR = [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId in:Trigger.newMap.keySet() limit 5000];
                for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:existingOCR) if(!existingOCRIds.contains(ocr.OpportunityId)) existingOCRIds.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
        
        
                //create the OpportunityContactRole objects for first time
                list<OpportunityContactRole> lstOCR = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();
                for(Opportunity opt:opportunities_in){
                    if(!existingOCRIds.contains(opt.Id) && contactsByAccount.get(opt.AccountId) != null){
                        for(Contact c: contactsByAccount.get(opt.AccountId)){
                            OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole(OpportunityId=opt.id, ContactId=c.id);
                            ocr.Role = 'Report Role (System Generated)';
                            lstOCR.add(ocr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //inserts exhisiting contact roles
                insert lstOCR;
        
                //Exhisitng contact roles
                List<OpportunityContactRole> currentOCR = new List <OpportunityContactRole>();
                Set<Id> currentOCRIds = new Set<Id>();
                currentOCR = [select Contactid from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId in:Trigger.newMap.keySet() limit 5000];
                for(OpportunityContactRole cocr:currentOCR) if(!currentOCRIds.contains(cocr.contactid)) currentOCRIds.add(cocr.contactid);
            
                //Update Exhisting Contacts on Account
                list<OpportunityContactRole> newOCRs = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();
                for(Opportunity opt:opportunities_in){
                    for(Contact c: contactsByAccount.get(opt.AccountId)){
                        if(!currentOCRIds.contains(c.id)){
                        OpportunityContactRole newOCR = new OpportunityContactRole(OpportunityId=opt.id, ContactId=c.id);
                        newOCR.Role = 'Report Role (System Generated)';
                        newOCRs.add(NewOCR);
                        }
                    }
                } 
            
                //inserts new contact roles
                insert newOCRs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey @MarkPond            

`for (Id accountId: accountIds){
            contacts = [select id, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];
            }`


is the block I have been trying to modify to grab all the contacts. I have tried using AccountContactRelationship and a couple of variables here to pull all associated contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(Opp.RecordTypeId != '0121I000001CDxfQAG' || Opp.RecordTypeId != '0121I000000JlQMQA0' ){
```

This is always true. You meant to say `&&` (AND) instead. To work this out in your mind, imagine the RecordTypeId is `0121I000001CDxfQAG`, it results in:

```
false || true
```

Which will be true, and the same for the other condition.

---

```
//get all contacts for those accounts
list<Contact> contacts = new list<Contact>();
//testing
for (Id accountId: accountIds){
    contacts = [select id, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];
}
```

This is just wrong. You only need to query once:

```
//get all contacts for those accounts
list<Contact> contacts = [select id, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];
```

---

```
Set<Id> existingOCRIds = new Set<Id>();
existingOCR = [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId in:Trigger.newMap.keySet() limit 5000];
```

This doesn't work, because you can't assign a query that way. You need to loop over the records:

```
Set<Id> existingOCRIds = new Set<Id>();
for(OpportunityContactRole role: [SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunities_in]) {
    existingOCRIds.add(role.OpportunityId);
}
```

---

Also, as a side note, you don't need to initialize a variable twice. You seem to be under the impression that this is somehow necessary.

Imagine writing:

```
Integer x = null;
x = 5;
```

You can just do:

```
Integer x = 5;
```

You do this as:

```
//get all contacts for those accounts
list<Contact> contacts = new list<Contact>();
//testing
for (Id accountId: accountIds){
contacts = [select id, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in: accountIds];
}
```

As an example. You don't need to initialize a variable more than once.

---

```
for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:existingOCR) if(!existingOCRIds.contains(ocr.OpportunityId)) existingOCRIds.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
```

This is just bad design. Always use optional braces. It makes the code more legible and thus easier to maintain.

Also, as a side note, you don't need to see if a Set contains a value before adding it; it does this automatically for you. That's the purpose of a Set.

```
for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:existingOCR) {
    existingOCRIds.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
}
```

---

Your entire code isn't properly [bulkified](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk), so your code will make mistakes on mass updates. Here's a better version to start from:

```
trigger InsertAccountContactsToOpportunityContactRole on Opportunity (after update) {
    Set<Id> ignoredRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>{
        sObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Employer Business').getRecordTypeId(),
        sObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Emerging Account').getRecordTypeId()
    };
    // Filter for records we intend to work on.
    Opportunity[] workingRecords = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!ignoredRecordTypeIds.contains(record.RecordTypeId) && record.AccountId != null) {
            workingRecords.add(record);
        }
    }
    // Nothing to do here?
    if(workingRecords.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    OpportunityContactRole[] newRoles = new OpportunityContactRole[0];
    Map<Id, Set<Id>> contactsByAccount = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
    Map<Id, Set<Id>> contactsByOpportunity = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
    // Initialize data structures; avoids all future if statements.
    for(Opportunity record: workingRecords) {
        contactsByAccount.put(record.AccountId, new Set<Id>());
        contactsByOpportunity.put(record.Id, new Set<Id>());
    }
    // Get direct contacts
    for(Contact record: [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :contactsByAccount.keySet()]) {
        contactsByAccount.get(record.AccountId).add(record.Id);
    }
    // Get indirect contacts
    for(AccountContactRelation record: [SELECT AccountId, ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = :contactsByAccount.keySet() AND IsActive = true]) {
        contactsByAccount.get(record.AccountId).add(record.ContactId);
    }
    // Get existing roles
    for(OpportunityContactRole record: [SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :workingRecords]) {
        contactsByOpportunity.get(record.OpportunityId).add(record.ContactId);
    }
    for(Opportunity record: workingRecords) {
        Set<Id> accountContactIds = contactsByAccount.get(record.AccountId);
        Set<Id> existingContactIds = contactsByOpportunity.get(record.Id);
        Set<Id> missingIds = accountContactIds.clone();
        missingIds.removeAll(existingContactIds);
        for(Id contactId: missingIds) {
            newRoles.add(new OpportunityContactRole(OpportunityId=record.Id, ContactId=contactId, Role='Report Role (System Generated)'));
        }
    }
    insert newRoles;   
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, testing it out now. Thank you! I've only been writing/learning apex for couple of weeks - this is extremely helpful.